# I'm having exception errors, file not found

Tags: c#, mklink

When i try to run this function it keep crashing when the process starts.

```
public static void MapDestinationToSource (string destination, string source)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
    // set the file to execute
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mklink";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/D \"{source}\" \"{destination}\"";
    // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    //proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    // start the process
    proc.Start ();
    // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
    // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
    // p.WaitForExit();
    // Read the output stream first and then wait.
    string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
    proc.WaitForExit ();
}
```

Exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception occurred
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at GameCloud.StorageLibrary.MapDestinationToSource(String destination, String source) in D:\Development\code\sample\server\ClientAgent\ClientAgent\StorageLibrary.cs:line 130
   at GameCloud.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Development\code\sample\server\ClientAgent\ClientAgent\Program.cs:line 135
```

When i execute the command on command line, it works. But it does not when in the code. I already set the security policies to allow the current user to execute the mklink command without elevated access.

Comment: You should probably use full path instead of just the file name...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, i dont find mklink in my windows folder. Some says that command is inside th windows terminal command prompt. So it does not have a binary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute command on cmd from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878810/how-to-execute-command-on-cmd-from-c-sharp)

Comment: @mjwills, i believe its different from that. but same as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621294/how-to-run-windows-command-mklink-from-vb-net-application

Comment: Also see http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/24/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Creating-symbolic-links-with-C_2300_.aspx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to execute executable programs (`bob.exe`) check out my striked out answer below.

Since you are trying to run `mklink` which is built-in to `cmd` then you need to use:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/C mklink /D \"{source}\" \"{destination}\"";
```

<strike>[The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) state:</strike>

> When UseShellExecute is true, the WorkingDirectory property specifies
>   the location of the executable. If WorkingDirectory is an empty
>   string, it is assumed that the current directory contains the
>   executable.

and then:

> When UseShellExecute is false, the FileName property can be either a
>   fully qualified path to the executable, or a simple executable name
>   that the system will attempt to find within folders specified by the
>   PATH environment variable.

As such, you need to either set `UseShellExecute` to `false` (so that your `PATH` is used to find the executable) *or* set `WorkingDirectory` to the folder that contains the executable.

Comment: mklink is within CMD shell, does tat means i need to set the cmd.exe as the working directory. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e4ffae45-b71c-493c-b0d2-cfeb0045f5c8/where-do-i-find-mklinkexe?forum=winserverfiles